# Using a looper live - how to connect playback and overdub to 2 different amps?

Tags: guitar-effects, amplifiers

I currently bought a Boss RC-2 Loop station because I want to play the second guitar in my band as well. My problem now is that I don't want the two guitar tracks - playback and overdub - to come from only one amp.
I even couldn't get from the manual how I can change the level and the effects of the overdub compared to the playback.
The manual only says that I should plug the guitar into the INPUT jack and connect the OUTPUT jack to the guitar amplifier...
My concrete questions are:

1. Where do I have to shift the effect pedal (Zoom G2)?
2. How can I attach a second amp to create a stereo sound?
3. How can I vary with level / effects so that only the overdub I am playing changes and the playback stays as it is??

Hope you can help me, I'm slowly getting frustrated ...
Cheers

Comment: Apologies, but it's unclear exactly what you are asking. It seems that want to be able to play in stereo with your Looper, but I'm lost in the details. Maybe you could revise your question a little bit so I can understand it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use Zoom in front of Your amp. In this case put RC-2 after Zoom and before amp.

So it will be:

**Guitar -> Zoom -> Boss -> Amp**

Alternative is putting Boss in the amp effects loop. This will be

**Guitar -> Zoom -> Amp -> Rc 2 -> Amp**

In those setups You will be able to record playback with one patch/sound, then change patch in G2 for overdub (and yes you can change sound for live playing for the next time).

All the tracks will be heard from Your amp's speaker. RC-2 is a mono unit so You can't split signal into two different amps.

In this setup You can prerecord tracks in home, they won't be affected by Your live Zoom g-2 opertaion.

Hope this help!